# Frame tricks in list plot overlap

Tags: plotting, output-formatting

Creating a ListPlot showing CfC emissions per year from 1961-2014, using FrameTicks but the years on the x-Axis overlap. The years are tied to emissions, so can't take any out. Suggestions on how to display every 5th year, but still keeping the data for each year? Please see code so far.

```
years = {1961, 1962, 1963, 1964, 1965, 1966, 1967, 1968, 1969, 1970, 
   1971, 1972, 1973, 1974, 1975, 1976, 1977, 1978, 1979, 1980, 1981, 
   1982, 1983, 1984, 1985, 1986, 1987, 1988, 1989, 1990, 1991, 1992, 
   1993, 1994, 1995, 1996, 1997, 1998, 1999, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 
   2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014};
cfcEmissions = {380000.`, 400000.`, 440000.`, 480000.`, 510000.`, 
   540000.`, 580000.`, 630000.`, 660000.`, 720000.`, 770000.`, 
   840000.`, 910000.`, 980000.`, 1.04`*^6, 1.05`*^6, 1.07`*^6, 
   1.07`*^6, 1.11`*^6, 1.08`*^6, 1.04`*^6, 1.1`*^6, 1.09`*^6, 
   1.15`*^6, 1.18`*^6, 1.28`*^6, 1.36`*^6, 1.46`*^6, 1.41`*^6, 
   1.32`*^6, 1.19`*^6, 1.08`*^6, 960000.`, 820000.`, 760000.`, 
   700000.`, 640000.`, 600000.`, 590000.`, 560000.`, 530000.`, 
   490000.`, 480000.`, 470000.`, 450000.`, 430000.`, 410000.`, 
   400000.`, 390000.`, 380000.`, 370000.`, 350000.`, 340000.`, 
   320000.`};
ListPlot[cfcEmissions, Joined -> True,
 PlotLabel -> "CfC Emissione [tonnes per year]",
 Frame -> {True, True, False, False},
 FrameLabel -> {"years", "CfC Emissions per year [tonnes]"},
 FrameTicks -> {Transpose[{Range[54], years}], 
   Range[300000, 2000000, 100000]},
 ImageSize -> Full]
```

[image: x-Axis is unreadable, would like to display every 5 year or so. If that doesn't work other suggestions would also be great]

Answer (score 2):

You can rotate the the dates so they don't overlap.

```
ListPlot[cfcEmissions,
  Joined -> True,
  PlotRange -> MinMax[cfcEmissions],
  GridLines -> {Select[Range[54], Mod[years[[#]], 5] == 0 &], 
  Range[300000, 2000000, 100000]},
  PlotLabel -> "CfC Emissione [tonnes per year]", 
  Frame -> {True, True, False, False}, 
  FrameLabel -> {"years", "CfC Emissions per year [tonnes]"},
  FrameTicks ->
    {Transpose[{Range[54], Rotate[#, 90 °] & /@ years}], 
     Range[300000, 2000000, 100000]},
  ImageSize -> 800]
```

[image: plot]

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using ListPlot with x,y coordinates for each datapoint.
Therefore Thread[] the two data lists (years and cfcEmissions).

Then simply adjust the FrameTicks to your wishes. For example, displaying every 5th year. I started the Y axis in 1960, but you may start at 1961. I think 1960 is just better looking.

```
 ListPlot[Thread[{years, cfcEmissions}], Joined -> True, 
 PlotLabel -> "CfC Emissione [tonnes per year]", 
 Frame -> {True, True, False, False}, 
 FrameLabel -> {"years", "CfC Emissions per year [tonnes]"}, 
 FrameTicks -> {Range[1960, 2015, 5], 
   Range[300000, 2000000, 100000]},
 ImageSize -> Full]
```

[image: Figure with every 5th year displayed]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the option [`DataRange`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DataRange.html) to specify the years.

```
{minYr, maxYr} = MinMax[years];

Manipulate[
 ListPlot[cfcEmissions,
  Joined -> True,
  DataRange -> {minYr, maxYr},
  PlotLabel -> "CfC Emissions [tonnes per year]",
  Frame -> {True, True, False, False},
  FrameLabel -> {"year", "CfC Emissions per year [tonnes]"},
  FrameTicks -> {Range[Round[minYr, 5], Round[maxYr, 5], 5],
    Range[300000, 2000000, 300000]},
  ImageSize -> Medium,
  Epilog -> {Red, 
    Line[{{yr, 0}, {yr, cfcEmissions[[yr - minYr + 1]]}}], Black,
    Text[Round@cfcEmissions[[yr - minYr + 1]],
     {yr, cfcEmissions[[yr - minYr + 1]]},
     1.5 {Sign[yr - Round[(minYr + maxYr)/2]], 1}, 
     Background -> White]}],
 {{yr, minYr, "year"}, minYr, maxYr, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image]